# Is there a way to add transformers to Kafka Strimzi MirrorMaker2?

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker, strimzi

Right now, I need to replicate some topics from one Kafka cluster to another, but in the second I need it in another format. We are using Strimzi in Kubernetes. In some connectors one can do something like this, but I am not sure if MirrorMaker2 let us do it since it is based on Kafka Connect:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1alpha1
kind: KafkaConnector
metadata:
  name: sample-connector
spec:
  class: com.sample.SampleConnector
  tasksMax: 2
  config:
    ...
    transforms: TimestampConversion,RectificationDateTimeConversion
    transforms.TimestampConversion.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
    transforms.TimestampConversion.format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
    transforms.TimestampConversion.field: timestamp
    transforms.TimestampConversion.target.type: string
    transforms.RectificationDateTimeConversion.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
    transforms.RectificationDateTimeConversion.format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
    transforms.RectificationDateTimeConversion.field: rectificationDateTime
    transforms.RectificationDateTimeConversion.target.type: string
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Whats the problem?

Comment: It does not work to me

Comment: I have been able to use Transforms fine in all connectors, including MM2... Perhaps it is Strimzi / kube-yaml that doesn't pass the properties correctly. I suggest using the Connect REST API to inspect and determine what properties are loaded

Answer (score 0):

It is true that MirrorMaker2 (MM2) is based on KafkaConnect, but it is for mirroring data as-is between Kafka clusters, in active/passive (unidirectional replication) or active/active mode (bidirectional replication).

What you really need is to deploy a KafkaConnect cluster and then add your custom Connector plugin with transforms. To be able to do this, you need to build a custom image starting from the Strimzi one, [as documented](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/using.html#assembly-kafka-connect-str).

There is also a [simple example here](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/try-it-out-on-kubernetes.html). Instead of copying the CamelKafkaConnector JARs to the plugin folder, you would copy your own, but the procedure is the same.